# "ls -lH" not following the link but "ls -lH linktofile" following it

Tags: ls, symlink

In a directory there is a link to some other file in some other directory.

If I give

```
ls -lHh
```

command with no arguments, ls does not resolves the symbolic link but if I give

```
ls -lHh *
```

or

```
ls -lHh linktofile
```

it then resolves the link.

Just curious, why?

Using GNU CoreUtils version 8.4

Comment: From the man page "    -H, --dereference-command-line
              follow symbolic links listed on the command line"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the object of the `ls` invocation is not the same. In the first case, the argument is the current directory (`.`), and the link is displayed only incidentally (because the argument is a directory and the link is in it). In the second case, it is among the explicitly listed arguments, and the special rule "follow symbolic links" applies only to the explicit arguments.

Comment: Got it! After reading your answer I did "ls -lHhR" without any argument and it followed/resolved it too. Thanks.